# How to redirect echo V >/dev/watchdog1 to a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to redirect output of following command to a file in shell
script:

```
echo V > /dev/watchdog1
```

Above command gives me following message on console

"watchdog stopped"

and I wanted to capture this in a file.

Tried this:

```
echo V > /dev/watchdog1 > output.txt
```

But this doesn't capture anything in output.txt.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Do what? `> /dev/watchdog1` already redirects the output to the file `/dev/watchdog1`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Who or what is generating the message? It's not the `echo` command and it's not one of the files being redirected to. You have to find out which program generates the output so that you can further work with it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tee` command to write to a file and at the same time write to standard output. Combined with a second redirection, this should allow you to write two files at the same time:

```
echo V | tee /dev/watchdog1 > output.txt
```

Comment: I just see "V"  in output.txt but this is not what I want.

Comment: @Milan Then what do you want? `V` is the output of `echo V`.